# Hora atual usando java script

Tags: javascript

Ele esta imprimindo a hora atual do sistema, mas quando abro o projeto na web, ele na atualiza a hora sozinho.
e eu quero saber também, como eu coloco os segundos logo apos o minuto. (pra fazer uma contagem certinha, igual relogio)
Sou iniciante, por isso o código esta ruim galera, aceito dicas

```
JS:
function carregar (){
var msg = window.document.getElementById ('msg')
var img = window.document.getElementById ('imagem')

var data = new Date ()
var hora =  data.getHours ()
var minuto = data.getMinutes ()
var segundos = data.getSeconds ()

if (hora >= 18){
    img.src = "./img/noite.jpg";
    document.body.style.background = 'Black'
    msg.innerHTML += `Boa noite, agora são ${hora}:${minuto}`
    
}
else if (hora <18 && hora >12){
    img.src = "./img/tarde.jpg";
    document.body.style.background = '#b9846f'
    msg.innerHTML += `Boa tarde, agora são ${hora}:${minuto}`
}
else if (hora >= 0 && hora <12){
    img.src = "./img/dia.jpg";
    document.body.style.background = 'rgb(70, 142, 236)'
    msg.innerHTML += `Bom dia, agora são ${hora}:${minuto}`
}
```

}

HTML:

Projeto horas

```
<script src="js.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Você pode utilizar o setInterval para deixar o relógio dinâmico

```js
var relogio = document.getElementById("relogio")

function updateClock() {
    var data = new Date(),
        hora =  data.getHours(), 
        minuto = data.getMinutes(),
        segundos = data.getSeconds() <= 9 ? "0"+data.getSeconds() : data.getSeconds() 

    relogio.innerHTML = `${hora}:${minuto}:${segundos}`
}

setInterval(updateClock, 1000)
```

```html
 <div id="relogio"></div>
```

O setInterval() recebe dois parâmetros: Função de callback (a função que você quer que seja executada em loop) e o temporizador que irá executar a função em loop, a cada X milisegundos

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/setInterval